# Scala case class as Ignite Cache key

Tags: scala, ignite, case-class

We are using Apache Ignite for caching in a Scala application.
For caching we use Scala case class as the cache key which has 2 parameter list.
The cachekey is as follows:

```
case class CacheKey(p1:String=null, p2:String=null) (ex1:String=null,ex2:String=null) {}
```

I am using the second param list to send some additional attributes to the Ignite server which is read in my Cache store implementation.

By default, Scala case class creates `hashCode()` and `equals()` using the fields in the first param list. Which means `ex1` and `ex2` will be ignored from `hashCode()` and `equals()`.
I have verified this to be true by creating simple test cases as well.

My expectations are that if my ignite cache has an entry with the key as `CacheKey("p1", "p2")(null, null)` I should get a cache hit when I try to get the cached value using the same values for `p1` and `p2` but any different values for `ex1` and `ex2`

I would expect `CacheKey("p1", "p2")("e1", "e2")` to get a cache hit. However that is not the case even though both the keys are equal.

Am I missing something?

PS: I have tested the results using `setOnheapCacheEnabled` as both `true` and `false`. It did not have any effect on the results.

Answer (score 3):

Ignite stores its data in "[binary object](https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/data-modeling/data-modeling#binary-object-format)" format. It does not use the hashCode and equals methods to determine equality. If you have optional properties, they would need to be part of the value object.

Comment: Thanks Stephen. The value object is being fetched from DB which would not serve my purpose. I need to be able to pass some specific attributes which should not influence the key equality.

Comment: If p1 and p2 are unique, then adding two additional columns would still be unique. You can add an index if you need to perform lookups using just p1 and p2. Records can be found using a SQL or Index query.

Comment: I am using the additional attributes for tracing since Ignite does not support it fully out of the box. I believe with the current format for storing keys and values, it may not be possible to do that by sending the trace attributes as additional params in the key.